# Solving systems of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to solve these equations in MATLAB?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what is wrong with [the solution posted here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657838/solving-systems-of-equations-in-matlab)?

Answer (score 0):

Lines 1 and 3 independent from lines 2 and 4, and can be solved easily.

Regarding lines 2 and 4, you can solve them using genetic algorithms with [gamultiobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gamultiobj.html) (which give a set of approximate solutions, aka. [Pareto frontier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency)):

run_ga.m:

```
FitnessFunction = @objectives;
numberOfVariables = 2;
options = gaoptimset('Generations', 100, 'PopulationSize', 100);
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT] = gamultiobj(FitnessFunction,numberOfVariables,[],[],[],[],[],[],options)
```

objectives.m:

```
function y = objectives(x)
   w = x(1);
   y = x(2);
   y(1) = abs(2*w*y-2*w+1);
   y(2) = abs(2*w+y^2-2*y-1);
```